# Symfony2 & PayPal - cURL error:14077410:SSL (sslv3 alert handshake failure)

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, curl, paypal

I'm trying to connect to Paypal's Sandbox server. For that I'm using the JMSPaymentCoreBundle and JMSPaypalCoreBundle.

But when I'm trying to connect an exception is thrown: `error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

My version of Symfony is 2.7.9. My version of curl is 7.43.0 and of OpenSSL is 1.0.2f.

I've looked for answers on the internet, and it looks like that now cURL request to use TLS 1.2 in order to use the PayPal sandbox. So I added: 
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,6);` (which is TLS 1.2)
in `vendor/jms/payment-paypal-bundle/JMS/Payment/PaypalBundle/Client/Client.php`

But now I've got the following error: `cURL Error: Unsupported SSL protocol version`

Thanks for helping ! (and sorry for my english)

Edit: So the error seems to come from the following parts

In my controller:

```
$instruction = $reservation->getPaymentInstruction();
if (null === $pendingTransaction = $instruction->getPendingTransaction()) {
    $payment = $this->ppc->createPayment($instruction->getId(), $instruction->getAmount() - $instruction->getDepositedAmount());
} else {
    $payment = $pendingTransaction->getPayment();
}

$result = $this->ppc->approveAndDeposit($payment->getId(), $payment->getTargetAmount());
if (Result::STATUS_PENDING === $result->getStatus()) {
    $ex = $result->getPluginException();

    if ($ex instanceof ActionRequiredException) {
          $action = $ex->getAction();

          if ($action instanceof VisitUrl) {
              return $this->redirect($action->getUrl());
          }

          throw $ex;
      }
} else if (Result::STATUS_SUCCESS !== $result->getStatus()) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Transaction was not successful: '.$result->getReasonCode());
}
```

In my vendor: (`vendor/jms/payment-paypal-bundle/JMS/Payment/PaypalBundle/Client/Client.php`)

```
public function request(Request $request)
{
    if (!extension_loaded('curl')) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('The cURL extension must be loaded.');
    }

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $this->curlOptions);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $request->getUri());
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
// Try but did not worl: curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST,     'TLSv1');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,6); // What i also add but error with my SSL protocol version not supported

etc.
```

When I add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,6);` in Client.php [I'v got that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG9qY.png)

And 
[when I don't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEsdq.png)

Comment: Could you post where in your code you experience the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing against the PayPal Sandbox API endpoints?
PayPal upgraded their Sandbox API endpoints last night to require TLS 1.2 and offering (only) a SHA256-signed certificate.

More details are here and here.

By the sounds of it, you're either trying to enforce something other than TLS 1.2 (likely), or your openssl libs are so old, they don't support TLS 1.2 (anything below OpenSSL 1.0.1c, so unlikely).

You may want to try running TlsCheck.php from the SDK

Comment: Thanks ! I'm going to look into that ! Just, I think you forgot the links ?

Comment: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US